# Sin wave with double trough length?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm not the best at maths but i'm working in 3D and need to create a formula for a spline object that is similar to the sin formula I already have (1).

`50*Sin(t*PI)`

but I need the trough to be double the length of the crest (2), I have done it manually for the image below

[sin wave double trough reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEFQC.jpg)

Any ideas much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One period-$1$ option is $\sin\min\left\{\tfrac{3\{x\}}{2},\,\tfrac{1+3\{x\}}{4}\right\}$, where $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. For a period $P>0$, replace $x$ throughout with $x/P$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, struggling to get my head around it. 

any idea how I could input it into this field? the list of operators and functions I have available are to the left

https://imgur.com/a/no4FJiY

Comment: @JamalBennett You get $\{x\}$ as `x-floor(x)`. Call that $y$; you get the rest with `sin(min(3*y/2, (1+3*y)/4))`. By the way, which programming language is this?

Comment: awesome thank you, and I know internally cinema 4d runs on python, as for the language inside of the formula object I don't know